# currentTarget unlink file method: POST ...possible??/

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Struggling with this: Would like to delete file (jpg or png) from server using this code - instead of a.jpg should be currentTarget. Is it possible?

```
function nDown_del(e): void
{

    e.currentTarget.filters = [Glow_del];
    //e.currentTarget.parent.removeChild(e.currentTarget);..............works
    mcPopup_del.cont_del.removeChild(e.currentTarget); ///...............works

    var proxy:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var vars:URLVariables=new URLVariables();
    vars.filethis ="a.jpg"; //e.currentTarget;
    req.data=vars;
    req.method= URLRequestMethod.POST;
    proxy.load(req); 
    var req:URLRequest=new URLRequest("http:....path to /php_file.php")
}
```

php_file---->

```
$src = $_POST [ 'filethis' ];

unlink($src);
```

Answer (score 2):

`e.currentTarget` is a display object not a file name so no you can't pass that to the server side and expect php to delete the file.

If `e.currentTarget` is a sprite you might need to extend the Sprite class and store your file name in it then you can access it from the `currentTarget` and send it to the server. Check out the following snippet :

```
class MySprite extends Sprite
{
    public string filename:String = "a.jpg";
}
```

In your handler :

```
function nDown_del(e): void
{
    var mySprite:MySprite = e.currentTarget as MySprite;

    if(!mySprite)
       return;

    mySprite.filters = [Glow_del];
    mcPopup_del.cont_del.removeChild(mySprite); ///...............works


    var proxy:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var vars:URLVariables=new URLVariables();

    vars.filethis = mySprite.filename;

    req.data=vars;
    req.method= URLRequestMethod.POST;
    var req:URLRequest=new URLRequest("http:....path to /php_file.php")        
    proxy.load(req); 

}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for your help Baris apprecjate it. I will try to sort it out....not so sure if its going to work